# Alpine Linux php-fpm serving PHP files as download instead of executing

Tags: php, nginx

I have a docker container for a Laravel project that I'm working on that is having trouble executing the PHP code as I desire. Instead of executing, the browser downloads the `index.php` file when I navigate to a route.

My server configuration is:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 default_server deferred ipv6only=on;
    listen 80 default_server deferred;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/rb-api/public;
    index index.php;

    # include h5bp/basic.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm82.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

My Nginx configuration is:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections 8000;
}

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

include conf.d/*.conf;

http {
  # include h5bp/security/server_software_information.conf;
  # include h5bp/media_types/media_types.conf;
  # include h5bp/media_types/character_encodings.conf;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  keepalive_timeout 20s;

  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on;

  include h5bp/web_performance/compression.conf;

  include h5bp/web_performance/cache_expiration.conf;

  map $sent_http_content_type $cache_control {
    default                           "public, immutable, stale-while-revalidate";
    ""                                "no-store";
    ~*application/manifest\+json      "public";
    ~*text/cache-manifest             ""; # `no-cache` (*)
    ~*image/svg\+xml                  "public, immutable, stale-while-revalidate";
    ~*application/(atom|rdf|rss)\+xml "public, stale-while-revalidate";
    ~*text/html                       "private, must-revalidate";
    ~*text/markdown                   "private, must-revalidate";
    ~*text/calendar                   "private, must-revalidate";
    ~*json                            ""; # `no-cache` (*)
    ~*xml                             ""; # `no-cache` (*)
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $x_frame_options {
    ~*text/html DENY;
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $content_security_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests";
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $permissions_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),browsing-topics=(),camera=(),display-capture=(),document-domain=(),encrypted-media=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),midi=(),payment=(),picture-in-picture=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),sync-xhr=(self),usb=(),web-share=(),xr-spatial-tracking=()";
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $referrer_policy {
    ~*text/(css|html|javascript)|application\/pdf|xml "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $coep_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "require-corp";
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $coop_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $corp_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
  }

  map $sent_http_content_type $cors {
    ~*image/                        "*";
    ~*font/                         "*";
    ~*application/vnd.ms-fontobject "*";
    ~*application/x-font-ttf        "*";
    ~*application/font-woff         "*";
    ~*application/x-font-woff       "*";
    ~*application/font-woff2        "*";
  }

  include http.d/*.conf;
}
```

h5bp is currently commented out.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM alpine:latest

ARG S6_OVERLAY_VERSION=3.1.6.0

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache zip xz unzip curl sqlite nginx bash shadow

RUN sed -i 's/bin\/ash/bin\/bash/g' /etc/passwd

ADD https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/v${S6_OVERLAY_VERSION}/s6-overlay-noarch.tar.xz /tmp
RUN tar -C / -Jxpf /tmp/s6-overlay-noarch.tar.xz
ADD https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay/releases/download/v${S6_OVERLAY_VERSION}/s6-overlay-x86_64.tar.xz /tmp
RUN tar -C / -Jxpf /tmp/s6-overlay-x86_64.tar.xz
RUN rm -f /tmp/s6-overlay*

RUN apk add --no-cache php82 \
  php82-common \
  php82-fpm \
  php82-gd \
  php82-pdo \
  php82-opcache \
  php82-bcmath \
  php82-zip \
  php82-iconv \
  php82-phar \
  php82-cli \
  php82-curl \
  php82-openssl \
  php82-mbstring \
  php82-tokenizer \
  php82-fileinfo \
  php82-json \
  php82-xml \
  php82-xmlwriter \
  php82-simplexml \
  php82-dom \
  php82-pdo_mysql \
  php82-pdo_sqlite \
  php82-session \
  php82-pecl-imagick

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/php82 /usr/bin/php

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN rm -rf composer-setup.php

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/php/ && \
  mkdir -p /var/run/nginx/ && \
  mkdir /etc/nginx/conf.d && \
  mkdir /etc/nginx/h5bp

RUN sed -i 's/;pid/pid/g' /etc/php82/php-fpm.conf
RUN sed -i 's/;cgi.fix_pathinfo=1/cgi.fix_pathinfo=0/g' /etc/php82/php.ini

RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/http.d/default.conf

COPY docker/development/etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY docker/development/etc/nginx/http.d/api.conf /etc/nginx/http.d
COPY docker/development/etc/nginx/h5bp /etc/nginx/h5bp
COPY docker/development/etc/php82/php-fpm.d/www.conf /etc/php82/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY docker/development/etc/s6-overlay /etc/s6-overlay

RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log
RUN ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

RUN adduser -h /var/www/ -u 1000 -G www-data -H -D -s /bin/bash api
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/ && chown -R api:www-data /var/www/
RUN groupmod -g 1000 www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/rb-api

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/init"]
```